# I can't send an image (socket & ngrok)

Tags: python, sockets, ngrok

Client:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import *
import socket, threading, base64
window = Tk()
window.title('Stream')
window.geometry('810x540')
window.configure(bg='black')
def GetPic():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('localhost', 8000))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    while True:

        #try:
        dir2 = r'C:\Users\SystemX\AppData\Local\Temp\screen_tr2.png'

        data = client_socket.recv(11111393216) # 
        data = base64.b64decode(data)
            
        with open(dir2, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(data)
                
        img = PhotoImage(file=dir2)
        lbl.configure(image=img)
        #except Exception as e:
        #    print(e)
            
#os.system(dir2)
lbl = Label(window, bg='black', image=None)
lbl.place(x=0,y=0)
threading.Thread(target=GetPic).start()
window.mainloop()
```

Server:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from tkinter import *
import socket, time, base64

dir = r'C:\Users\SystemX\AppData\Local\Temp\screen_tr.png'

ip, port = 'IP:PORT'.split(':')

timee=time.time()
print('started')
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((ip, int(port)))
while True:

    #time.sleep(2)
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
    print(f'grabbed ({time.time() - timee}s)')
    screenshot.save(dir)
    print(f'saved ({time.time() - timee}s)')
    with open(dir, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
        #print(content)
        enc = base64.b64encode(content)
        client_socket.send(enc)
        #client_socket.send(content)

#server_socket.close()
```

The image is interrupted during transmission. How can I fix this?

The image is not fully transmitted.
ngrok appears to be disrupting the image. Maybe there are other suitable means of opening ports?
When transferring an image without base64 decoding, the image also breaks.

Comment: What do you think you are doing with `recv(11111393216)`?  That's just utter nonsense.  What you're missing is that TCP is a streaming protocol, not a packet protocol.  If one side sends a megabyte, you might get it in 100 byte chunks.  You do not get one `read` per `send`.  It is YOUR responsibility to keep reading more and more until you get all you are expecting.

Comment: okay, I apologize for my code

Comment: Why are you base64-encoding the image? There is no need, it's not JSON, sockets can safely/correctly transmit binary data. You're just needlessly making your transfer 30% larger.

Comment: Change your `send()` to `sendall()` in your sender. In your receiver, use `fd = socket.makefile()` then `data = fd.read()`

Comment: Separately, you will encounter another problem in this code after you fix the socket transfer.  In what I consider a serious bug in tkinter, the `lbl.configure` method does not take a reference to the image object that is passed in.  When your function exits, the `img` will be deleted and the label will go blank.  You need to store that in a global, or tuck it into a global list.

Comment: Also, you are currently trying to update that label from a thread.  That's not allowed.  ALL access to the GUI must be done from the main thread.  You can use the `after` method to get a callback in the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you solve the socket part of your issue.  I've changed the server so that it loops on the "read" until it returns 0, which happens when the socket closes.  This allows it to receive the entire image.  Note that I've added `break` to both loops so that it doesn't go forever.  I've also removed the tkinter parts, to avoid confusing the issue too much.

Note that you have the "server" and "client" backwards.  The one doing the "accept" is the server.  The one doing "connect" is the client.  I also removed the `ImageGrab`, since that doesn't work on Linux with Wayland, which I have.

Server:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import socket

BUF = 16384
def GetPic():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('localhost', 8000))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    dir2 = 'p2.png'
    while True:
        data = b''
        while True:
            buf = client_socket.recv(BUF)
            if not buf:
                break
            data += buf
            print(len(buf),len(data))
            
        print('received',len(data),'bytes')
        with open(dir2, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(data)
        break

GetPic()
```

Client:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import socket, time, base64

dir = 'xxxxxx.png'

ip, port = 'localhost:8000'.split(':')

timee=time.time()
print('started')
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((ip, int(port)))
while True:
    with open(dir, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
    print('sending',len(content),'bytes')
    client_socket.sendall(content)
    break
```

Philosophically, what you are doing is a poor way to echo a desktop image to another computer.  There are well-established and highly optimized tools that allow you to do that task.